# Building a PySpark job to handle repeated sampling and transformations efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on building a pyspark job, and I have a question more about what approach to use to build my job. I have a list of **SUBJECTS**, which I take a sample of 500 elements (with return) 1000 times, and for each of these samples I filter out my spark dataframe and make some transformations and append the result in a dataframe that will hold data for all samples. The idea is, since each sampling will be having duplicated values hence I can't filter ou the dataframe by the list of values, since for duplicated values I want to have two lines (or 3+) in the dataframe and the ID column will have the ID concatenated with (1,2,3...) and then for each sample I will have a column which is SampleNb. The goal in here is to make transformations on the dataframe. The difficulty I find is to build this dataframe while using the distribution of spark.

PS: nbSample >=1000
What I have tried:

```
def randomly_choose_subjects_2(sujet, consoOldBase, nbSample):
'''Returns a dataframe that contains all sampled data.
      Parameters:
           Sujet(pd.Dataframe): Contains Subjects
           consoOldBase(spark.Dataframe): dataframe of conso data
      Returns:
           Df_Output(spark.Dataframe): dataframe with all sampling data
'''
#Normalize weight factor by having a sum of 1 for probability
sujet['NORMALIZED_WEIGHT'] = sujet['WEIGHTING_FACTOR'] / sujet['WEIGHTING_FACTOR'].sum()
# Sample subjects with replacement for all iterations
sampled_subjects = np.random.choice(sujet['SUBJECT'], size=(nbSample, sujet.shape[0]), replace=True, p=sujet['NORMALIZED_WEIGHT'])
return sampled_subjects
#Schema of the dataframe that will hold all sampling data
consoOldBase_Schema = StructType([
StructField("SUBJECT", StringType()),
StructField("SURVEY_DAY", IntegerType()),
StructField("FOOD_CODE", StringType()),
StructField("FOOD_AMOUNT_CORRECTED", DoubleType()),
StructField("WEIGHTING_FACTOR", DoubleType()),
StructField("NUMBER_DAYS", DoubleType()),
StructField("Iteration", IntegerType())
])
#Creating an empty dataframe with the same schema as the dataframe we will be working on
Df_Output = spark.createDataFrame([],consoOldBase_Schema)
for i in range(0,nbSample) :
    #This will return unique elements from numpy array and their counts
    unique_elements, counts = np.unique(sampled_subjects[i], return_counts=True)
    #zipping Subjects with their occurences => Dict
    dict_elements = dict(zip(unique_elements.astype(str),counts))
    #to keep count of the iteration No
    ind = 0
    #When sampling some subjects are picked more than once, we will loop through them and substract 1 on each iteration 
    while (sum(dict_elements.values())>0):
        #Filter ConsoOld by values of subject sampled from Sujet table
        #subBase = consoOldBase.filter(consoOldBase.SUBJECT.isin(list(np.unique(sample_suj).astype(str))))
        subBase = consoOldBase.filter(consoOldBase.SUBJECT.isin(list(dict_elements.keys())))
        #if it's not the first iteration append ind value to Subject
        if(ind > 0):
            subBase = subBase.withColumn("SUBJECT", concat(subBase.SUBJECT,lit('-'), lit(ind)))
        #Create a column for sample iteration Number
        subBase = subBase.withColumn("Iteration", lit(i+1))
        #Append output to dataframe
        Df_Output = Df_Output.union(subBase)
        ind += 1
        #substract 1 from values of occurences in dict
        dict_elements = {k: v - 1 for k, v in dict_elements.items() if v>1}
 #Return a dataframe that contains data of all the sampling
return Df_Output
```